# Invarient Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component , Occurs when using conditional operator in React Native

Tags: react-native

After using conditional operator to display some components based on some conditions, I got this error. Following is the code.

```
    {this.state.isOk==false ?  (
    <View>
       <TextInput value={this.state.title } />
       <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorTitle}</Text>
       <TextInput  value={ this.state.company }  />
       <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorCompany}</Text>
       <View>
          <CheckBox value={this.state.isCurrent} /> 
       </View>
       {this.state.isCurrent==false ? (  
       <Date
       value={this.state.from }
       placeholder={strings("user_profile.from")}
       maxDate={moment().subtract(1, "years")}
       onChange={time => {
       this.setState({ from: time });
       }}/>
       <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorDate}</Text> 
) : null}
       <TextInput label={this.state.location}  />
       <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorLocation}</Text>
       <TextInput  multiline={true} value={ this.state.description} />
       <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorDesc}</Text>
    </View>
    ): null}
```

> this is the  style for Text component

```
  errorText: {
    color: "red",
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

Comment: Instead of `null` you must render a component.

Comment: If you have nothing to show when your condition is `false`, then skip `Ternary operator` instead use `&&` operator - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @ravibagul91 tried both cases. issue still exists

Comment: post your `state` and `LocalStyles`

Comment: post a complete `LocalStyles` structure and your state

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `null`, which is handled like a text in this context,  you should return an empty `<View/>`.

Comment: I've tried this way. But still no use. The code was working fine even with the null. Issue arised after adding <Text style={LocalStyles.errorText}>{this.state.errorXXXX}</Text>

Comment: @unknown123 post your `LocalStyles`. Also your state.

Comment: @unknown123 could you please provide an example ( maybe on https://snack.expo.io/ )?